# Can I prevent Unity from sleeping when not focussed?

Tags: unity, macos

Every time I click away from the player either within the editor or from a build, on MacOS, it pauses. For my use case this is incredibly annoying. It appears to be related to apple's "app nap" feature, which as far as I can tell apple have seen fit to remove the option to disable.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about a feature of the Apple operating system, not a feature of Unity. You might get better answers about this on the [Ask Different StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to Apple software/hardware. If you choose to post your question there, be sure to delete the copy here, to avoid leaving dead ends for future searches.